# Is correct name enough to make it happen?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I've just dipped into `limits.h` by Microsoft. I tried to check what's the return type for `max()` function and to my surprise I see something like this:

```
// TEMPLATE CLASS numeric_limits
template<class _Ty>
    class numeric_limits
        : public _Num_base
    {   // numeric limits for arbitrary type _Ty (say little or nothing)
public:
    static _Ty (__CRTDECL min)() _THROW0()
        {   // return minimum value
        return (_Ty(0));
        }

    static _Ty (__CRTDECL max)() _THROW0()
        {   // return maximum value
        return (_Ty(0));//EXACTLY THE SAME WHAT IN min<<------------------
        }
//... other stuff
};
```

How is it possible that in both `min` and `max` return exactly the same? Does it mean that if I would write makeSanwich() return (_Ty(0)) it would make a sandwich for me? How is it possible that having this same code with just the function names different we are getting different results?

Comment: (And no, sandwich will not be made. Not even with `sudoMakeSandwich`.)

Comment: That file is called `<limits>`, BTW (even though some implementations will use some file `limits.h` internally).

Comment: @Konrad: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/sandwich.png `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is implemented through template specialization. Probably, you'll find something like this elsewhere:

```
template<>
class numeric_limits<int> : public _Num_base {
    public:
        static int min() {
            return INT_MIN;
        }
        static int max() {
            return INT_MAX;
        }
};
```

If you use `numeric_limits<int>` the above specialization will be preferred over the general case. There are similar specializations for `float`, `char` etcetera.

Only if none of these match, the general case will be selected. In that case, the compiler will try to construct an object of type `_Ty` from the `0` constant. Why that is ever useful... I don't know. I would rather have a compilation error instead.

Answer (score 6):

That’s not the relevant code.

`numeric_limits<T>` is specialized for the native integer types and **in these specializations** the relevant values/logic is implemented. Look there.

The above code is a blanket code for all non-specialized types and they will indeed return the same value for both `min()` and `max()`. Try it yourself:

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    foo(int x) : x(x) {}
};

bool operator ==(foo const& a, foo const& b) { return a.x == b.x; }

assert(std::numeric_limits<foo>::min() == std::numeric_limits<foo>::max());
```

… I’m not sure that this behaviour is mandated by the standard, though. The above code could equally provoke a compile-time error since `numeric_limits` hasn’t been specialized for `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do some more looking, you'll probably find that there are specializations for specific types, and those specializations return more meaningful values.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the "generic limits" for an undefined type. So its results are no relevant. If you look below, you'll see:

```
template<> class _CRTIMP2_PURE numeric_limits<char>
    : public _Num_int_base
    {   // limits for type char
public:
    typedef char _Ty;

    static _Ty (__CRTDECL min)() _THROW0()
        {   // return minimum value
        return (CHAR_MIN);
        }

    static _Ty (__CRTDECL max)() _THROW0()
        {   // return maximum value
        return (CHAR_MAX);
        }
// etc.

};
```

Which is the specialization of the generic template for the type `char`, which gives the result you need.

For example, when you write:

```
int iMax = std::numeric_limits<char>::max() ;
```

it will use the specialized version of numeric_limits *at compile time*, and thus, put CHAR_MAX's value into variable iMax.